# How to perform incremental aggregation in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a collection of user's browsing time.

> db.userBrowsing.find()

```
{ userID: "ed3p6ddk0r", start_time: ISODate('2011-11-03 14:17:00'), time: 75 } );
{ userID: "2bnliaossn", start_time: ISODate('2011-11-03 14:23:00'), time: 10 } );
{ userID: "rhjynj9z8o", start_time: ISODate('2011-11-03 15:02:00'), time: 5 } );
{ userID: "q3wasyu5yp", start_time: ISODate('2011-11-03 16:45:00'), time: 20 } );
```

By aggregation, I maintained the *totalBrowsingTime* collection which contains userID and totalTime.

> db.userBrowsing.find()

```
{ userID: "ed3p6ddk0r", totaltTime: 75 } );
{ userID: "2bnliaossn", totalTime: 10 } );
{ userID: "rhjynj9z8o", totalTime: 5 } );
{ userID: "q3wasyu5yp",totalTime: 20 } );
```

Day by day this collection populate for every user. So I need incremental aggregation to fill *userBrowsing* collection. 
Should I use cronjob for this? or is there any different method for that?
Thanks!

Comment: have you thought perhaps about running a cron-job process that will run the aggregations daily (or hourly) and store them in another collection?

Comment: Why don't you let the application do that? the same application that writes in your `userBrowsing` will also write the other information in your `totalBrowsingTime` collection

Comment: @asosnovsky yes. If I use cron-job then I need a method for filter latest data which are not processed early.